# Register for the Hardware Developer Program have not "Hardware"

Tags: windows, authentication, driver, publish

I want to release the driver program developed under Windows 10 to Microsoft. According to Microsoft's release process, I need to register for the Hardware Developer Program first. But when I registered, I found only two options, and in comparison, I chose the first one. After entering the dashboard, it was found that "hardware" could not be clicked
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TeQm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9EVW.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQYwL.jpg)

I chose the first one to register and compared it with the options in the registration. I suspect that only accounts authorized by Microsoft can use the "hardware" feature?